# SIE export locked behind a paywall

Tags: contract-law, data-ownership

I am based in Sweden under Swedish and EU laws.

Recently (during 2023) the accounting platform that I use converted their tiers from free to fee, during this transition they notified their users that the application will be locked behind a paywall, and if you as the user would not want to keep using their software they are inclined to change during a period of time.

Missed opportunity for me, I did not take any actions during that period, I did neither "accept" any new terms. To my surprise when I was going to export my companys SIE file which I would then use in another accounting software, it has now been locked behind their paywall.

This means that I have to pay for a subscription to get my companys data out from their software, which is not something I signed up for during the free plan year 2020.

Is it legal to only offer a time limited period of exporting the data, even if the customer was signed up for the free plan? I feel like I am being blackmailed since an account platform is required for post in Sweden.

Comment: are you sure your data even still exists? However, I have to inform you that we can not offer legal advice in such a matter - or any matter. If you need legal advice, you need to contact an attorney in your country. Often a first consultation is available for free or with a limited price. In general, you might look for an attorney that specializes on terms of services or contracts.

Comment: I understand, I thought this community knew if there was any general laws in EU regarding such a manner. Thank you for your time, I will look somewhere else then!